# Reverse proxy in front of Google Artifact Registry (GAR)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine

Using GAR, requires the usage of some "generic" URLs, like europe-west-1-docker.pkg//

We would like to use a custom URL and then load balance to the proper registry based on that URL/path. For example:

Requests to "generic-container-url.internal.some.org/production" should be directed the registry named "production".

Considering that, (this known workaround)[https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/hack-your-own-custom-domains-container-registry] would not fully apply as it only covers the case of container images and other registries are to be considered, including: maven, npm, pypi...

Using some cooked solution like Nexus Repository Manager to proxy each registry could be a partial solution, at least for "read" access, but it would not be enough to provide "write" access.

More and more, it is starting to look like we will need to configure some VM instance to run something like an nginx and struggle to deal with authentication for reading/writing into each type of repo ourselves.

I wonder what could be the "good approach" or if this is a dead end. Question is, how would you deal with this?

Comment: What problem are you solving?

Comment: URL of GAR repos is subject to project name, which under certain conditions needs to change (project migration for example), easing URLs for developers/cicd tools, standardization with other tools we use in our enterprise are the reasons why we would like to use a custom URL rather than the generic ones provided by Google for using GAR repositories.